# C++ Switch statement to assign struct values

Tags: c++, struct, switch-statement

*I am trying to assign one struct object with values from a different struct for whatever bird type was selected using a switch statement. However, I am getting the `conflicting decoration` error. How can I resolve this?

```
   /**
   temp and humidity control points
*/
struct chicken_config
{
  char *node_type = "incubator";
  char *sub_type = "chicken";       // set the type of incubator
  int sub_type_id = 1;
  int hot = 102;                //set hot parameter
  float optimum_temp = 99.5;    // set optimum_temp temp to go to b4 turning off
  float cold = 89.9;            //set cold parameter
  int high_hum = 65;            //set high humidity parameter
  int optimum_hum = 60;         // set optimum humidity parameter to go to b4 turning off
  int low_hum = 55;             // set low humidity parameter
};

struct turkey_config
{
  char *node_type = "incubator";
  char *sub_type = "turkey";        // set the type of incubator
  int sub_type_id = 2;
  int hot = 102;                //set hot parameter
  float optimum_temp = 99.5;    // set optimum_temp temp to go to b4 turning off
  float cold = 89.9;            //set cold parameter
  int high_hum = 65;            //set high humidity parameter
  int optimum_hum = 60;         // set optimum humidity parameter to go to b4 turning off
  int low_hum = 55;             // set low humidity parameter
};

struct peacock_config
{
  char *node_type = "incubator";
  char *sub_type = "peacock";       // set the type of incubator
  int sub_type_id = 3;
  int hot = 101;                //set hot parameter
  float optimum_temp = 99.5;    // set optimum_temp temp to go to b4 turning off
  float cold = 98.9;            //set cold parameter
  int high_hum = 65;            //set high humidity parameter
  int optimum_hum = 60;         // set optimum humidity parameter to go to b4 turning off
  int low_hum = 55;             // set low humidity parameter
};

struct chameleon_config
{
  char *node_type = "incubator";
  char *sub_type = "chameleon";     // set the type of incubator
  int sub_type_id = 4;
  int hot = 81;                 //set hot parameter
  float optimum_temp = 77.5;    // set optimum_temp temp to go to b4 turning off
  float cold = 76.5;            //set cold parameter
  int high_hum = 95;            //set high humidity parameter
  int optimum_hum = 85;         // set optimum humidity parameter to go to b4 turning off
  int low_hum = 75;             // set low humidity parameter
};


// structure for current incubator configuration
struct current_config
{
  char *node_type = "incubator";
  char *sub_type;               // set the type of incubator
  int sub_type_id;
  int hot;                  //set hot parameter
  float optimum_temp;       // set optimum_temp temp to go to b4 turning off
  float cold;               //set cold parameter
  int high_hum;             //set high humidity parameter
  int optimum_hum;          // set optimum humidity parameter to go to b4 turning off
  int low_hum;              // set low humidity parameter
} currentConfig;
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

The following is where I'm having trouble.

```
    // setup directed sub-type
void switch_sub_type(int sub_type)
{
  switch (sub_type)
  {
    // assign the bird type params
    case 1: chicken_config currentConfig;
    case 2: turkey_config currentConfig;
    case 3: peacock_config currentConfig;
    case 4: chameleon_config currentConfig;
  }
  return;
}
```

ANY suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This declaration char node_type = "incubator"; does not make a sense. You are trying to initialize a single character with a string literal.

Comment: You have defined five different unrelated and incompatible `struct` types. I strongly suspect that you need something very, very different. How about one `struct` type and five different values?

Comment: how are they unrelated? They have elements of the same types and are of the same lengths.

Comment: They are unrelated because they have different names.

Comment: BTW, consider using a naming convention where structure names are of a different style than variables (and members).  This will make differentiating structures from variables a lot easier.

Comment: I would really like to keep the structures as close to what I have presented here. Is there no way to assign those parameters to be 'currentConfig'  and have the ability to change that if needed?

Comment: Research inheritance, i.e. search the internet for "C++ inheritance".  Put all the common fields into the base class.  Use child classes to initialize some of the fields.  See my answer.

Comment: Now is a good time to start a habit of using `std::string` instead of character arrays.  Character arrays can overflow, and the pointer system presents more difficulty when placed into a structure (such as either copying the value of the char pointer or making a duplicate *string*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several relevant problems in your code

1. The C `struct` concept seems to be wrong: You can define a single `struct` type with a specific set of parameters and create several instances of this `struct`. For your case, you could create a basic animal_config struct and one instance per each animal you want to include into your code.

This way, you can create a generic config:

```c
    struct animal_config
    {
      char node_type;
      char sub_type;        // set the type of incubator
      int sub_type_id;
      int hot = 102;                //set hot parameter
      float optimum_temp;    // set optimum_temp temp to go to b4 turning off
      float cold;            //set cold parameter
      int high_hum;            //set high humidity parameter
      int optimum_hum;         // set optimum humidity parameter to go to b4 turning off
      int low_hum;             // set low humidity parameter
    };
```

And then assign different values to it depending on the condition:

```c
    void switch_sub_type(int sub_type)
    {
      switch (sub_type)
      {
        // assign the bird type params
        struct animal_config currentConfig;
        case 1: 
          animal_config.node_type = "incubator";
          animal_config.sub_type = "chicken";
          animal_config.sub_type_id = 1;
          animal_config.hot = 102;
             ...
          };
          break;
        case 2:
        ...
      }
      return;
    }
```

2. I don't know if this is just a minimal example, but the `switch_sub_type` method is not returning anything or storing the currentConfig anywhere. It will be erased from the stack after the function call has finished. Following my previous example, maybe you want to return the `currentConfig` object to the caller:

```c
    struct animal_config switch_sub_type(int sub_type)
    {
      switch (sub_type)
      {
        // assign the bird type params
        struct animal_config currentConfig;
        case 1: 
          animal_config.node_type = "incubator";
          animal_config.sub_type = "chicken";
          animal_config.sub_type_id = 1;
          animal_config.hot = 102;
             ...
          };
          break;
        case 2:
        ...
      }
      return currentConfig;
    }
```

3. Regarding your switch-case clause, maybe you need to include a `break;` statement after each case. Otherwise, if a case is selected, all cases after it will be executed too, producing (probably) undesired behavior.

Comment: `animal_config = {` is incorrect, you cannot assign to a type .  Another option would be to have `const` objects predefined for the possibile initializers and then the switch statement just does simple assignment

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is only possible for initialization. I will fix it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have two recommendations:  one struct, severable variables; and one base class, several child classes.

### One Struct, Many variables

According to your code, each bird could be a different instance of the same structure.

```
struct Bird_Config
{
  char *node_type;
  char *sub_type;       // set the type of incubator
  int sub_type_id;
  int hot;                //set hot parameter
  float optimum_temp;    // set optimum_temp temp to go to b4 turning off
  float cold;            //set cold parameter
  int high_hum;            //set high humidity parameter
  int optimum_hum;         // set optimum humidity parameter to go to b4 turning off
  int low_hum;             // set low humidity parameter
};

int main()
{
   Bird_Config chicken;
   chicken.hot = 102;

   Bird_Config turkey;
   //...
   return 0;
}
```

### Base Class and Inheritance

Another implementation could be using a parent/base class and many child classes:

```
struct Bird_Config
{
      char *node_type = "incubator";
      char *sub_type;       // set the type of incubator
      int sub_type_id;
      int hot;                //set hot parameter
      float optimum_temp;    // set optimum_temp temp to go to b4 turning off
      float cold;            //set cold parameter
      int high_hum;            //set high humidity parameter
      int optimum_hum;         // set optimum humidity parameter to go to b4 turning off
      int low_hum;             // set low humidity parameter
};  

class Chicken_Config : public Bird_Config
{
     Bird_Config::sub_type = "chicken";
     //...
};

The inheritance model allows you to do something like this:  
int main()
{
   std::vector<Bird_Config *> configs;
   Bird_Config * p_bird = new Chicken_Config;
   configs.push_back(p_bird);
   p_bird = new Turkey_Config;
   configs.push_back(p_bird);
   //...
   for (int i = 0; i < configs.size(); ++i)
   {
      std::cout << "Bird Configuration["
                << i
                << "]: "
                << configs[i]->sub_type
                << "\n";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

In the above example, you don't need to `switch` based on the configuration type.  The inheritance mechanism (polymorphism) will handle that for you.

Comment: Disagree with the inheritance suggestion - it overcomplicates the code, and a vector of raw pointers is difficult to use correctly (again, overcomplicating the code to avoid memory leaks)  . It'd be far simpler to just have `vector<Bird_Config>` and initialize the values normally